# Наследование JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте, почему не получается наследовать панельку?

```
 settingButt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            PanelSett panel2 = new PanelSett();
            if(onClickSett == false) {
                panel.add(panel2);
                System.out.println("1");
                panel.repaint();
                onClickSett = true;
            }
            else{
                panel.remove(panel2);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                onClickSett = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

в консоле успешно выводится 1, но панелька не появляется

класс PanelSett

```
public class PanelSett extends JPanel{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    this.setSize(100, 100);
    this.setBackground(Color.red);
    this.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("2");
}} // В консоле даже 2 нет
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите мой пример на Вашей основе, в нем по нажатию кнопки показывается и скрывается панель:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class PanelTest {
        public boolean onClickSett;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PanelTest panelTest = new PanelTest();
            panelTest.start();
        }

        private void start() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                PanelSett panel2 = new PanelSett();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                JButton button = new JButton("Push me");
                panel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                frame.add(panel);
                button.addActionListener(e -> {
                    if (onClickSett == false) {
                        panel.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        panel.revalidate();
                        panel.repaint();
                        onClickSett = true;
                    } else {
                        panel.remove(panel2);
                        panel.revalidate();
                        panel.repaint();
                        onClickSett = false;
                    }
                });

                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            });
        }
    }

    class PanelSett extends JPanel {
        public PanelSett() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
            this.setBackground(Color.red);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

По Вашему коду:
paintComponent - не вызывается и в нем не стоит устанавливать свойства, который ставяться они один раз при инициализации, ну кроме фона, но его лучше менять через отдельный метод. Размер также зависит от менеджера компоновки, но в большинстве случаев не используется.

Так же при каждом нажатии Вы создаете новую панель, следовательно старая не удалится так как она неравна новой, а именно этот метод вызывается при remove().